# Exporting logs using journald / rsyslogd

Tags: logging, systemd, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I am trying to export kernel logs (/var/log/messages) to remote Syslog servers.  Till now, most of the system logs are stored in journald currently and rsyslogd is disabled.

So, I am planning to use rsyslogd to export logs (By configuring the rsyslog.conf file). Firstly, I will pass those kernel logs from journald to rsyslogd and then export them.

Can someone suggest if this is the right path to proceed or I can use directly journald to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

Systemd can collect and store logs, but it doesn’t have a built-in method of logging to remote locations such as log management systems. Instead, it relies on the device’s syslog service to relay messages between journald and a remote syslog server.

> However, syslog is text-based and the journald uses a binary format,
> so your logs need to be converted before they can be transferred. You
> can do this by using either systemd’s ForwardToSyslog configuration
> setting, or by using rsyslog’s imjournal module.

*/etc/systemd/journald.conf* has a `ForwardToSyslog=yes` option that would allow you to forward the logs to syslog, which seems like a pretty inelegant way to me.

---

In rsyslog you can add the module `imjournal`, to get the *journal* logs. To use it, add the following to your */etc/rsyslog.conf* file. The mmjsonparse module lets ryslog parse journald messages:

```
module(load="imjournal")
module(load="mmjsonparse")
```

Kernel messages can be logged with the standard the `imklog` module. Just add: `module(load="imklog")` to the configuration file */etc/rsyslog.conf*. With the standard rsyslog configuration, this should log kernel messages to */var/log/messages* and */var/log/syslog*.

The forwarding can be done over [UDP or TCP](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tcp-vs-udp/).

**Forwarding:**

```
*.* action(type="omfwd" target="10.0.2.1" port="514" protocol="udp")         # UDP
*.* action(type="omfwd" target="10.0.2.1" port="10514" protocol="tcp")       # TCP
```

**Obsolete Legacy Format**

```
*.* @10.0.1.1:514        # UDP -> one @
*.* @@10.0.1.1:514       # TCP -> two @s
```

After adding this, your rsyslog client should start forwarding the messages to your remote syslog server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! ForwardToSyslog=yes will only enable forwarding logs from journald to rsyslogd? However, my aim is to export them to remote servers so I guess I need to use "imklog" solution only right?

Comment: @TanikaGarg I've updated my answer, I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to forward logs using rsyslog according to standards RFC3164, RFC3339 & RFC5124?

Comment: Please post this as a new question so other users can benefit as well. Then I'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389726/export-logs-using-rsyslog-in-various-formats