# Export logs using Rsyslog in various formats

Tags: logging, systemd, rsyslog

I am trying to export kernel logs (/var/log/messages) to remote Syslog servers using rsyslog.

I am required to export in various standard formats like RFC3339, RFC3164, and RFC5424. Can someone please tell me how to solve this issue? I believe this attribute needs to be used:

```
# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

The format used in your question **deprecated**. You can still use it, but if you're writing a config from scratch I would recommend using the new "advanced" rsyslog format.

```
template(name="someName" type="string" string="messageFormat")
```

---

**RFC3339** message template:

```
template(name"RFC3339_Format" type="string"
         string=""%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n""
        )
```

**RFC3164** message template:

```
template(name="RFC3164_Format" type="string"
         string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag:1:32%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg%\n"
        )
```

> Note to sysklogd users: sysklogd does not support RFC3164 format, which is the default forwarding template in rsyslog.

**RFC5424** message template:

```
template(name="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format" type="string"
         string="<%PRI%>1 %TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %APP-NAME% %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %msg%\n"
         )
```

> the format specified in IETF’s internet-draft ietf-syslog-protocol-23, which is very close to the actual syslog standard RFC5424. This format includes several improvements. You may use this format with all relatively recent versions of rsyslog or syslogd.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I tried the above solution with RFC3339 format using 
kern.* action(type="omfwd" target="TARGET" port="514" protocol="udp" template="RFC3339_Format"). But I see the system has stopped forwarding logs to the remote TARGET.