# Logging in rfc5424 format?

Tags: python, logging, rsyslog

I'm using Python 3.7.  I want to log to a remote rsyslog server using RFC-5424 over UDP.  The problem is, logging.handlers.SysLogHandler is producing what looks like the old RFC-3164 format:

```
<14>2022-05-29 14:40:08,746 [none] INFO spi.views.foo: hello
```

I see a couple of third-party packages ([rfc5424-logging-handler](https://github.com/jobec/rfc5424-logging-handler) and [syslog-rfc5424-formatter](https://github.com/easypost/syslog-rfc5424-formatter)) that generate 5424 format but given that RFC-5424 has been around for 13 years, it is surprising that there's no native way to do this.  Am I missing something obvious, or do I really need to load an external package?

Comment: The mere existence of an RFC doesn't mean anybody is using it. I haven't seen wide adoption of RFC5424 anywhere, so it's not surprising to find support lacking in Python's `logging` module. Apparently nobody has found it important enough to contribute the support (or possibly the existing 3rd party modules work well enough that there's no motivation for Yet Another Implementation).

Comment: As @larsks said, RFC5424 isn't used often - RFC3164 still is the standard format in most syslog loggers. You can [create a template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72390927/7558856) for rsyslog, to create RFC5424 compliant logs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like the answer really is that the standard library doesn't support RFC-5424, despite the fact that the docs for SysLogHander.emit() makes a vague mention of it.

I ended up going with syslog-rfc5424-formatter, mostly because it had more users.  It seems to work fine.